# Matlab: How to use 'bitxor' for more inputs than 2?

Tags: matlab

I hope someone can help me with this particular problem:

I need to calculate 'bitxor' for more than two inputs. I have a vector of intputs/elements where the number of inputs/elements varies. For instance, in case of a four elements Vector, the solution is as follows:

Vector: `Y = [1 3 5 7];`

Solution: `bitxor(bitxor(Y(1),Y(2)),bitxor(Y(3),Y(4)));`

Is there any way where I can write this in a more general way, such that I get one value/elemet no matter how many inputs elements there is in vector Y?

Comment: First of all define the operator for general arrays with N elements

Answer (score 1):

A 'back of the envelope' solution seems to be to convert each number in the list to binary and sum up the number of `1`s in each bit column.

If the sum in a particular column number is even, then that column will hold a `0` in your final (binary) result, if it is odd, it will hold a `1`.

So your example of `bitxor([1 3 5 7])`:

```
0001 (dec 1)
0011 (dec 3)
0101 (dec 5)
0111 (dec 7)
====
```

Bit-wise sum: `0224`  (Not base 2 here, obviously)

Convert via even/odd rule above:

```
0224 => bin 0000 (or dec 0)
```

I tried it on a few quick examples offhand and didn't run into an exception.

So some code to try the solution out:

```
Y = [1, 3, 5, 7];
strMat = dec2bin(Y); % Convert Y to char matrix of binary values

for i = 1:size(strMat,2)
    colSum = sum( str2num(strMat(:,i))); % Sum up each column
    finalVal(i) = num2str( mod(colSum,2)); % Check whether column sum is even
end

finalVal = bin2dec(finalVal); % Convert solution to decimal
```

Comment: Ryan J. Smith - thank you! You saved my morning. It looks like it is working for all possible cases.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I will describe now is far from being optimal, but you can give it a try anyway:

```
Y1 = Y(1:2:end);
Y2 = Y(2:2:end);
arrayfun(@(i) bitxor(bitxor(Y1(i),Y2(i)),bitxor(Y1(i),Y2(i))),1:size(Y1,1))
```

Comment: @user2329754: that's OK, I do not mind, up to you picking the solution you like the most :)

Answer (score 0):

This is another solution ,  but it overwrites the original vector.

```
Y = [1, 3, 5, 7];

for i=1:length(Y)-1
    Y(i+1) = bitxor(Y(i),Y(i+1)); 
end
finalVal = Y(end)
```